# Is a client certificate encrypted during the ssl handshake

Tags: security, authentication, ssl

During an SSL handshake with client authentication, is the client certificate encrypted when it is transmitted by the browser to the server?  In other words does the symmetric key exchange occur BEFORE the client certificate is transmitted?  I assume it is else a listener could steal the certificate right?

Comment: There is no need to steal the certificate because the certificate will be for the set domain; if, later on, a domain provides a certificate for another domain that's a fail. Certificate numbers are also usually checked with the certificate authority by the browserso a forgery changing the name on the certificate will be quickly discovered.

Comment: [Further information](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices)

Comment: I was referring to a client certificate from a personal certificate .pk12 type file

Answer (score 1):

With TLS 1.3 both server and client certificates are encrypted, with TLS 1.2 and lower they are send in clear.

> I assume it is else a listener could steal the certificate right?

A certificate is usually not considered secret information. Only the private key matching the public key in the certificate is secret, but this private key is not transmitted.

Comment: The client certificate is signed by an authority whose public key is held on the server and this is all that is required.  Nothing is signed by the client cert so if it were taken then it could be used by a different person to authenticate.  However if as you say it is encrypted with TLS 1.3 that would prevent such an attack.  Thanks.

Comment: @dave110022: *"... and this is all that is required."* - No. The client provides proof of ownership of the client certificates private key to the server, the same as the server provides proof ownership of the server certificates private key to the client. Without this proof being successful the authentication fails.

Comment: That is new information to me.  How does the client cert provide proof of ownership? Does it sign something with itself as part of the authentication package? Can you point me to the relevant documentation that goes through the detail?

Comment: @dave110022: Yes, the client signs some unique data (i.e. no replay possible) which are based on client and server parts of the handshake. The server verifies this signature. For the relevant part in TLS 1.2 see [CertificateVerify](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.8). See also [How does a server validate the Certificate Verify message in SSL/TLS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138411/how-does-a-server-validate-the-certificate-verify-message-in-ssl-tls)

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful.